# Calculation of intercept in multiple linear regression (OLS)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, least-squares

While researching OLS, I found out the equation to calculate coefficients as:

$$
\beta = (X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top y
$$

(Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares)

However it does not explicitly mention how to calculate the intercept. So what is the equation to calculate it?

Comment: Typically the first column of $X$ is a column containing 1’s that correspond to the intercept. Then the first $\beta$ calculated according to the formula above will be the estimated intercept.

Comment: @Dimitris Rizopoulos, I tried that with the following input but it didn't work:            X=[[1, 3, 3.2], [1, 3.5, 3.6]] and y = [118.4, 135.2]

Comment: you cannot estimate three coefficients from two data points. You need at least three data points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can obtain the solution for the intercept by setting the partial derivative of the squared loss with respect to the intercept $\beta_0$ to zero. Let $\beta_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ denote the intercept, $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^d$ the coefficients of features, and $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ the feature vector of the $i$-th sample. We have to solve

\begin{align}
\arg\min_{\beta_0} \quad& \mathcal{L}(\beta_0, \beta) \\
\mathcal{L}(\beta_0, \beta) &= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \beta_0 - x_i^\top \beta)^2 \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_0} \mathcal{L}(\beta_0, \beta) &=
-\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \beta_0 - x_i^\top \beta) = 0
\end{align}

All we have to do is to solve for $\beta_0$:

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \beta_0 &= \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - x_i^\top \beta) \\
\beta_0 &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - x_i^\top \beta) 
\end{align}

Usually, we assume that all features are centered, i.e.,
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij} = 0 \qquad \forall j \in \{1,\ldots,d\},$$
which simplifies the solution for $\beta_0$ to be the average response:
\begin{align}
\beta_0
&=
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^d x_{ij} \beta_j
\\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i - \sum_{j=1}^d \beta_j \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij}
\\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i
\end{align}

If in addition, we also assume that the response $y$ is centered, i.e.,
$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i = 0$, the intercept is zero and thus eliminated.